# Hyper-V VM fail with at end of iSCSI boot

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, remote, iscsi, san

I have a Hyper-V VM (generation 1) booting from iSCSI

The OS in the iSCSI target is Windows 10
it loads almost all of the of the system
and fails at end with "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE" error

try with 32 and 64 bit Windows10 but no candy...
Googled everywhere and no candy also...

When I boot the VHDX in a VM it works fine
so the Hyper-V drivers must be there (NIC/Storage/...)

?any ideas

Comment: Try to enable AHCI mode in the VM's BIOS, if it can be done.

Comment: I dont see the point Harry... the storage controllers in the vm are IDE emulatiors and the controller for iSCSI is a SCSI/Network block drive emulator??? also the VM is working fine...
can you explain and give more technical details about your argument?

Comment: Your post then is unclear regarding SCSI/IDE. Please give more details.